# How to reuse sessions or steps?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I use now Cucumber in order to describe tests for features. Since our application is a web application, there will be the obligatory login step at the beginning of the each test case.
I can now add to each .feature file a test case with the scenario:

```
Scenario: Login user
        Given Open Chrome and start application
        When I enter valid username and password
        Then User shall be logged in successful
```

But I would prefer a solution without doing this and to continue with a session quiet after the first .feature file had been processed.
Is this possible? In case of yes, how?

Comment: Are you looking to reuse a driver and browser instance across feature files?

Comment: if so you can check [gherkin with qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options to achieve this. One is to use the "Background" section in each feature file that replicates those exact steps. You could just introduce an extra validation on the step definition for example to check if Chrome is running then it would not be started again, etc. The caveats with this approach is that the login action still has to be performed on each feature and the background section needs to be included on each feature file.

```
Feature: Feature 1

  Background: User is Logged In
    Given Open Chrome and start application
    When I enter valid username and password
    Then User shall be logged in successful

  Scenario: Scenario 1 in Feature 1
    ...

  Scenario: Scenario 2 in Feature 1
    ...
```

Another option is to tag the scenarios that require the user to be logged in (e.g. @requiresUserLoggedIn) and check if that tag is present on a Before Hook, then trigger the login process if that is not the case. This is the approach I would follow.

```
@requiresUserLoggedIn
Scenario: Scenario 1 (requires user to be logged in)
  ...

Scenario: Scenario 2 (does NOT require user to be logged in)
  ...

@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {
    if(scenario.getSourceTagNames().contains("requiresUserLoggedIn)) {
        // Check if the User is Logged In and Trigger Login Process if that is not the case
    }
}
```